# Hashset size issue

Tags: java, hashset

Here In below example i have created hashset in which i am adding three string values 
s1,s2,s3 though it shows me size of hashset 1. Why?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s1="abc";
    String s2=new String("abc");
    String s3="abc";
    Set setdemo=new HashSet();
    setdemo.add(s1);
    setdemo.add(s2);
    setdemo.add(s3);

    System.out.println("s1 hashcode -:"+ System.identityHashCode(s1));
    System.out.println("s2 hashcode -:"+ System.identityHashCode(s2));
    System.out.println("s3 hashcode -:"+ System.identityHashCode(s3));
    System.out.println("Set size is -:"+setdemo.size());
}
```

output:

```
s1 hashcode -:17523401
s2 hashcode -:8567361
s3 hashcode -:17523401
Set size is -:1
```

Comment: String equality is tested via the overridden equals() method. That method takes into account the content of the String. Which is why while s1 != s2 , s2 won't be in the set. s1.equals(s2) returns true.

Answer (score 5):

Set does not allow duplicates. As strings are put into a pool, they all point to the same instance.

Comment: They don't all point to the same instance, since String s2 is not put into the string pool.

Comment: @ghdalum is right sudhanshu they dont point to same instance. s2 is a new instance even the hascode o/p says the same.

Comment: Set interface designed to keep different objects. s1.equals(s2) is true. So that the size of HashSet will remain as 2

Answer (score 2):

`Duplicate` is identified as having an **equivalent hash code**, and returning `true` when tested for **equality**.

In your case, all the 3 `Strings` are identified as **duplicates** and since `Set` eliminates duplicates, the size is `1` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Because in HashSet only unique entries are saved. Here "abc" is added 3 times so only String abc will be saved even though you add it number of times

Answer (score 0):

A HashSet doesn't store multiples of equal objects - it is a "set". You should use a MultiSet (also known as Bag) implementation for example from Apache Commons Collections or from Guava - these store also the number of copies you have added.

Answer (score 0):

[`HashSet.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29)

> adds the specified element `e` to this set if the set contains no
>   element `e2` such that `(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))`

So, during the above add operations:

`s2.equals(s1)` returns `true`, `s2` does not get added.

`s3.equals(s1)` returns `true`, `s3` does not get added to the `setdemo` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the String is going to have the similar hashCode returned by the hash() function. And Set doesn't allow duplicates it will certainly overwrite the previous value at that position.

Answer (score 0):

Check output for

```
s1.equals(s2)
s2.equals(s3)
```

Its `String` class equals method which is not allowing you to add the same object again and again because HashSet uses equals method for identifying whether objects are same or not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create a object of String class, it checks if value is already stored in some other string.
like

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 = "hello";
```

In this case, it won't allocate two memory locations for s1 and s2, but only one. When we check using .equals() operand, it checks for memory location which comes out to be the same. 
In :

```
setdemo.add(s1);
setdemo.add(s1);
setdemo.add(s1);
```

We are creating three memory locations (in simple terms), and but when HashSet internally checks(again in simple terms) for .equals, it tells it same memory location and hence size of HashSet is 1.